# Many to many android room ref extra variable

Tags: android, android-room, android-room-relation

I have a Many to Many relationship set up on my Room database denoted by the following diagram:

[image: Relationship diagram]

eveything works great but I would like to make the following addition:
[image: Updated relationship diagram]

My question is **how do I go about having RecipeWithIngredients get this unit:String variable from the RecipeIngredientRef Entity when a recipeWithIngredients is constructed on a query?**

```
    @Entity(indices = [Index(value = ["name"],unique = true)])
data class Recipe(
    var name: String,
    val image: String?
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "recipeID")
    var ID: Long = 0
}

@Entity(indices = [Index(value = ["name"],unique = true)])
data class Ingredient(
    val name: String,
    val image: String?,
    val amount: Int
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ingredientID")
    var ID: Long = 0
}

@Entity(primaryKeys = ["recipeID", "ingredientID"])
data class RecipeIngredientRef(
    val recipeID: Long,
    val ingredientID: Long,
    val unit: String
)

data class RecipeWithIngredients(
    @Embedded
    val recipe: Recipe,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "recipeID",
        entity = Ingredient::class,
        entityColumn = "ingredientID",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = RecipeIngredientRef::class,
            parentColumn = "recipeID",
            entityColumn = "ingredientID"
        )
    )
    val ingredients: List<Ingredient>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in way using current many-to-many Relations in Room for that. So I just want to save your time for researches.

This `RecipeIngredientRef` table is used internally just for two other tables' join and for now adding there additional fields will not help to get these fields with @Relations/Junction mechanism.

You can try workarounds, but they are no so elegant and they needed to dig deeper into Room's result's processing:

1. Don't use @Relation/Junction mechanism for `RecipeWithIngridients` at all, write your own query with two JOINs (since you should get data from 3 tables). As a result you'll get some raw set of records and then you should use loops and methods of Kotlin collections to turn result into needed form.
2. Use @Relation/Junction mechanism, but after getting result - make additional processing of result - make one more query to `RecipeIngredientRef` table and set missing `unit` value manually (again with loops and methods of Kotlin collections).